# Signal chain for tone detection?

Tags: embedded, signal-processing, goertzel-algorithm

I'm trying to make an embedded thingy that detects the presence of a 19kHz tone from an electret microphone.  I have a multistage bandpass filter/preamp hooked into the ADC of a microcontroller, and am trying to figure out the best way to digitally condition the signal in order to detect the presence of the tone.

I have implemented a Goertzel filter to look for the frequency of interest.  My ADC takes 400 samples at a frequency of 4000KHz, then the micro processes the block and adds the result to a 100 point moving average.  Looking at terminal output after each block, I can definitely see an overall jump in the numbers when the transmitter is turned on.  However, there's a lot of noise in the power readings when the thing is turned on, and the the noise floor in the room I'm in keeps changing, too.  I am not sure how to tune the thresholding level/filter out all of this noise.

I've tried a few things, but they all seem to be pretty noisy as the baseline of my signal drifts all over the place:

- Preprocessing the block with Hamming/Blackman windows
- Ratio of total received block power to band power in filter output
- Ratio of power of band in interest (19kHz) to a band outside of,
  but near band of interest (18.5kHz)

EDIT:  I've done some more reading since posting this.  Is calculating (2*Ew)/(N*Et) where Ew is the output from my filter and Et is the sum of the squares in my block the best way to do this test?

Any advice on how to deal with this and/or do a better method of signal extraction?

Thanks!

Comment: Sample rate of 4000KHz (== 4.0 MHz)?  Is that a typo?

Comment: Sampling theory (aka the Nyquist theorem) says you only need 38kHz to sampling to detect 19kHz.   And unless this is very specialized hardware, your mic likely cannot detect much above 20kHz (approximate upper limit of human hearing).  There's a reason audio is usually sampled at 44kHz or 48kHz.  So unless you have another reason for running your ADC that fast (i.e. another input), there's no reason to sample anywhere near that fast.  With that in mind, make sure nothing above sampling freq/2 gets through your bandpass or you'll have aliasing problems.

Comment: As others have said, your sample rate is either mischosen or misstated, and do not forget that most systems will want a lowpass rolloff band below nyquist.  There are some very small electrets that will work at your frequency though the most common ones will not - you may do better with an analog output MEMS microphone.  Finally detection/noise rejection will be easier if you use frequency shift keying rather than simple presence/absense.

Comment: Sorry everyone, that was indeed a typo.  Should have been 40,000Hz.